# How do I limit the amount of job console log on Jenkins?

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

From time to time I encounter jobs that end-up putting Jenkins down because they log too much to the console, sometimes due to an more or less endless loop or too much verbosity.

I am looking for a solution that would prevent/stop/kill spamming jobs.

We are using Jenkins pipelines and **all** these occasional spamming jobs are inside `sh()`, which makes me think that maybe we should add some kind of smart wrapper.

Please, do not suggest fixing the spamming source instead. I asked this question because I want to prevent this kind of issue from outside the potential spammer script, that's because we have hundreds of jobs and because is impossible to avoid a sooner or later spamming bug caused by a developer mistake.

Shortly: we cannot control what is run inside the shell script, but we can control how the shell is run.

Comment: I assume you're familiar with [shell output redirection](http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/redirection.html) to `/dev/null`? Aka `sh "oh-my-god.sh > /dev/null"`.

Comment: what about limit the logs? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783471/limiting-log-size-of-jenkins-log-or-hudson-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours wasted with various attempts to address this I was able to come up with a working solution that looks like:

```
def sh2(script) {
    sh '''( ''' + script + ''' ) 2>&1 | tee output.log | awk -v offset=${MAX_LINES:-200} '{ if (NR <= offset) print; else { a[NR] = $0; delete a[NR-offset] } } END { for (i=NR-offset+1; i<=NR; i++) { if (!match(a[i],"^[[:space:]]*$")) print a[i]} }
}
```

You can find the latest version at https://github.com/ssbarnea/rhos-ci/blob/master/vars/sh2.groovy in case I will find other bugs or improvements.

As you can see it will limit both head and tail to 200 lines if MAX_LINES is not defined. If defined it will be used.

This solution is the only one that does not repeat output when the total number of lines is <200. Also it does work in streaming mode, so you do see the output in real time.

Note: the linked version has extra features, like ability to log full output to auto-sequenced log files.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin that stops jobs if their console log has exceeded a defined size limit.

It is  called "[Build log file size checker](https://plugins.jenkins.io/logfilesizechecker)"

If your normally successful job logs are consistent in size, and do not vary hugely, then this could help you distinguish the looping or spamming ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the returnStdout variable to your `sh` calls like so:

```
node(){
    // Eliminates returned output (you can also redirect this to a variable!)
    sh returnStdout: true, script: 'echo hi; echo hi; echo hi; echo hi;'
    // Has the normal output
    sh script: 'echo hi; echo hi; echo hi; echo hi;'
}
```

Which changes to the output like so:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on ***
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[***] Running shell script
+ echo hi
+ echo hi
+ echo hi
+ echo hi
[Pipeline] sh
[***] Running shell script
+ echo hi
hi
+ echo hi
hi
+ echo hi
hi
+ echo hi
hi
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
```

If you need to automate this so that everybody does this by default, you should look into building a Groovy Shared Library that is auto loaded in your Jenkins instance (I recommend this for more large users anyways!). Once you have that set up, make a new script for executing shell steps and ask users to use that instead of the normal `sh` step

Here's a good starting doc for that stuff: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: I am already doing the shared library part, the big problem was on how to modify or rewrite the `sh()` to make it limit the stdout output. Keep in mind that I do *not* want to lose the live-streaming feature. Theoretically this could be implemented using just a bash wrapper, still I was not able to find a fully working solution in bash yet, just lots of incomplete ones.